# Combine values with column names as new column

Tags: r, data-transform

I like to combine my values with column names(See current set and required set):

[image: Current and required set]

Current set = 
- ncol = 9
- nrow = 26814

I want to add the values from `SheetNaam` to the columns `XYEAR` to expand my columns and decrease my rows, without losing data or 'NA'. Is this possible in R?

Difficult to explain by text, hope someone will understand my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `gather` and `spread`.  `gather` the columns that `starts_with` 'X' followed by numbers, `unite` the 'SheetNaam', 'key' into a single column and do `spread` back to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, key, val, matches("^X\\d+$"), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
     unite(SheetNaam, SheetNaam, key, sep = "") %>%
     group_by(SheetNaam) %>%
     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
     spread(SheetNaam, val)
```

Comment: I receive the following error:Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 2280 rows:

Comment: @LiekeOltheten  May be you can duplicate elements.  Try the updated version

Comment: I will, thank you so much, when I add a 'number' before the set it creates the column number but also a unwanted matrix, probably easaly solved with duplicate, Thanks!

Comment: @LiekeOltheten  As the data provided is an image, it is difficult o test.  As @Sotos mentioned, if you can provide a `dput` off a small example and expected output, would be easier